# how to assign value to hidden field of struts html tag in javascript

Tags: struts, textfield, hidden

i am using struts 1.3 i have requirement of hidden field , i am assigning value in hidden in javascript but when try to read value of hidden field in action class its coming blank

```
     var dataobj="{data:["code:"+c1,"name:"+n1]}";
     document.getElementsByName("data").value=dataobj;
     <html:hidden property="data"   />
```

where iam doing wrong not understanding

Answer (score 1):

Look at JavaScript errors in your browser error console. The following is not valid JavaScript code:

```
var dataobj="{data:["code:"+c1,"name:"+n1]}";
```